# Play Framework: handling timeout over controller promise

Tags: java, playframework, promise, akka

all my app's controllers (Play Framework 2.2.4, Java) return an F.Promise: now there is one controller where I switch to another akka context as its computation time can be longer. The context switch is pretty straigthforward as you can use the api:

```
return F.Promise.promise(...,executionContext)
```

and configure the custom executionContext in the application.conf. Now the problem comes when the computation is longer than a specified amount of time (let's make it 20 seconds): I am not able to make the Promise timeout.Consider that I don't want to invoke the get(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS) method on the promise as I am sure that play will do that in its guts.I searched for some configuration property in the akka executionService and found this

```
thread-pool-executor {
    # Keep alive time for threads
    keep-alive-time = 60s

    # Min number of threads to cap factor-based core number to
    core-pool-size-min = 8

    # The core pool size factor is used to determine thread pool core size
    # using the following formula: ceil(available processors * factor).
    # Resulting size is then bounded by the core-pool-size-min and
    # core-pool-size-max values.
    core-pool-size-factor = 3.0

    # Max number of threads to cap factor-based number to
    core-pool-size-max = 64

    # Minimum number of threads to cap factor-based max number to
    # (if using a bounded task queue)
    max-pool-size-min = 8

    # Max no of threads (if using a bounded task queue) is determined by
    # calculating: ceil(available processors * factor)
    max-pool-size-factor  = 3.0

    # Max number of threads to cap factor-based max number to
    # (if using a  bounded task queue)
    max-pool-size-max = 64

    # Specifies the bounded capacity of the task queue (< 1 == unbounded)
    task-queue-size = -1

    # Specifies which type of task queue will be used, can be "array" or
    # "linked" (default)
    task-queue-type = "linked"

    # Allow core threads to time out
    allow-core-timeout = on
  }
```

but neither the **keep-alive-time** nor the **allow-core-timeout** properties are useful to timeout the long computation promise.

I tried to change the return type to something like:

```
F.Promise<Result> original = F.Promise.promise(...,customExecutionService);
return F.promise.timeout(original,10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

but this just postpone the execution by 10 seconds.(the timeout method documentation is very confusing)

Other snippet I tried is:

```
F.Promise<Result> original = F.Promise.promise(...,customExecutionService);
  return F.promise.timeout(original,10,TimeUnit.SECONDS).get(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

but this timeout the external Wrapper promise.

So I am now coming to the conclusion that I have to write my own custom executionService that sets up a timeout listener and throws the TimeoutException by itself but i am sure there is some kind of easier path to take in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution by wrapping the original response (the one that doesn't timeout) with the following code:

```
Future<T> error = after(Duration.create(delay,unit),Akka.system().scheduler(),main,
                Futures.failed(new TimeoutException("Future timed out")));

return Promise.wrap(Futures.firstCompletedOf(
    Lists.newArrayList(original.wrapped(),error), main));
```

```

Where **main** is the main execution context, **after** is taken from akka Patterns. Basically if the original promise takes more than the **duration** passed in the error future kicks in by throwing a Timeout Exception.

I put that in a filter so every controller annotated with that filter shares the same behaviour.